# Make dijit.form.currencytextbox accept negative value with one digit after decimal

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo, dijit.form

I am using `dijit.form.currencytextbox` and want to allow negative values. when I give value `'-0.1'` I get the error  :

> 'value entered is not valid'

When I give value `'-0.10'` the value is accepted as valid.

How can I make `'-0.1'` as a valid value.
I have tried adding `contraints-places:2` to make the entered value convert to two digits after decimal but that has not made any difference.
`'0.1'` gets automatically formatted `'$0.10'` and gets accepted as a valid input.

```
<input type="text" id="amountTextBox" data-field="amount" maxlength="10" 
       required="required" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox"
       value="0" data-dojo-props="constraints:{min:-9999999.99,max:9999999.99,places:2}, 
       currency:'USD', trim: true, intermediateChanges: true" />
```

Comment: which version of dojo you're using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to  Dojo version issue

please set your project to newer version and it should work

See this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/gv73bvws/) whcich Uses dojo 1.12

Also see working snippet :

```js
require(["dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/on",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(CurrencyTextBox, Button, On) {
  var fp = new CurrencyTextBox({
    currency: 'USD',

    value: -0.1,
    constraints: {
      places: 2
    }
  }, 'currency');

  var btn = new Button({}, "btn");


  console.log(fp);
  fp.startup();

  On(btn, "click", function(e) {
    console.log(fp.get("value"))
    alert(fp.get("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<div id='currency'></div>
<br /><br />
<body class="claro">
  <div id='btn'>
    Alert value
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks @bRIMOs updating to the latest package resolved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome @user1579234 , So please think mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer ) :) may be it'll help others

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to do that. I will do that for sure when I have got enough points.